# Google sheets sum if within specific week

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheets budget and I am trying to write something to keep track of how much money I have spent in a specific week.

Link to my example budget below.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15HP24iDd-kZ-MydKwgbMCoG0rCHN_DNOcBZsm0HhKQ0/edit?usp=sharing

I am already using sumif() to say, if the entry's CATEGORY says "Gas" then add theAMOUNT to the Gas row in the table. I want to add another parameter that will sum the amounts if the entry's CATEGORY says Gas AND is within the specified week above the table...(WEEK 31).

I hope this makes sense if you need more clarification I will try my best to do so.

Comment: Have you tried `=SUMIFS()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Diego suggested, SUMIFS()should work. Example

```
=sumifs($C$4:$C$9, $D$4:$D$9, "=week "&$I$3, $B$4:$B$9,$F4)
```

An alternative would be to use sumproduct().

```
=sumproduct($D$4:$D$9="week "&$I$3, $B$4:$B$9=$F4, $C$4:$C$9)
```

You should be able to fill down this formula (as far as needed) for the other categories.